# clang on QtCreator Windows

Tags: qt, clang, llvm, qt-creator

I'm trying to use clang on QtCreator Windows. Had already build llvm and clang following [Building Clang natively on Windows/MinGW](http://here-be-braces.com/blog/building-clang-natively-on-windows-mingw) and also had configured a kit on Qt Creator to use clang. But in the compilation log I still see g++ being called. So I modified the .pro adding:

```
QMAKE_CXX += C:/llvm/bin/clang++.exe
```

Now, checking the Makefiles I see:

```
CXX           = g++ C:/llvm/bin/clang++.exe
```

How to get rid of this `g++`?

Comment: += means concatenate, whereas = means replace

Comment: did you use clang build from Visual C++ distribution? which works with MS codegen at backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign with `=` instead of `+=`:

```
QMAKE_CXX = C:/llvm/bin/clang++.exe
```